# SharePoint Site Collection Not Rendering

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Good afternoon.  I am new to the SharePoint world, and I have recently inherited responsibility for SharePoint 2013 administration.  I have created several site collections.

Sometimes, when I attempt to view the site collections, they render properly.  Other times, I receive the errors below.

I attempted to view one of my site collections, and the following happened in various browsers.

```
Chrome - Returned "This webpage is not available" message.
Internet Explorer - The page hung, and nothing was displayed.
Firefox - Displayed the following:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 20:35:33 GMT
Connection: close
```

I know that the site collection exists because

1. it is in the list of site collections on the Central Administration
   page
2. I viewed it before today.

Can anyone recommend any troubleshooting tips?  I'm wondering about logs or traces I can review.

Comment: how many WFE you have in farm?

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting.

1. If you have more than 1 WFE, Directly hit the each WFE and see if both are working or 1 up and 1 down.
2. also try to reset IIS on WFE
3. Use Fiddler to trace the traffice at what point it fail
4. Also Check the IIS log, event log and ULS logs for more clue.

Comment: We have 1 WFE.  I will try your suggestions.  Thank you.